# Difference in Git merge order?

Tags: git

Is there any difference between

```
git merge c1 c2
```

and

```
git merge c2 c1
```

? Also, is there any difference between

```
git checkout c1
git merge c2
```

and

```
git checkout c2
git merge c1
```

?

Comment: Not sure about the first one. For the second one, it makes a difference as to which branch you merge on, if c1 and c2 are on different branches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are merges in Git symmetric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192526/are-merges-in-git-symmetric)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The end result in terms of the file content should be the same in all cases you described.

But there will be a difference in the *DAG*, in the ordering of commits in the graph of all commits, for example:

#### Case 1: `git merge c1 c2`

```
*   dd24250 (HEAD, master) Merge branches 'c1' and 'c2'
|\  
| * 9d09bec (c2) change in c2
* | 1f5c0ca (c1) change in c1
|/
```

#### Case 2: `git merge c2 c1`

```
*   3256c8d (HEAD, master) Merge branches 'c2' and 'c1'
|\  
| * 1f5c0ca (c1) change in c1
* | 9d09bec (c2) change in c2
|/
```

#### Case 3: `git checkout c1; git merge c2`

```
*   111e7da (HEAD, c1) Merge branch 'c2' into c1
|\  
| * 9d09bec (c2) change in c2
* | 1f5c0ca change in c1
|/
```

#### Case 4: `git checkout c2; git merge c1`

```
*   8ccf531 (HEAD, c2) Merge branch 'c1' into c2
|\  
| * 1f5c0ca (c1) change in c1
* | 9d09bec change in c2
|/
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the second question.

The resulting tree objects in the merge commits will be identical.
However the two commit objects won't be:

The order of the two parent commit objects will be different.
Which may lead to subtle differences when referring to commits with the `HEAD^1~5` notation.

The same applies to the first question:

1st case, 1st parent = current branch last commit, 2nd parent = c1 last commit, 3rd parent = c2 last commit.

2nd case, 1st parent = current branch last commit, 2nd parent = c2 last commit, 3rd parent = c1 last commit.