# Is git merge-base commutative?

Tags: git

Consider

```
$ git merge-base <original-branch> <new-branch>
```

**Question:** is `git merge-base` commutative? That is, does the above command yield the same result as

```
$ git merge-base <new-branch> <original-branch>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but since there can be multiple merge bases, I would guess that the answer is **no**.

Comment: See also the great answer from Christopher here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12198219/5414160

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is only one merge-base, then yes.
Meaning: `git merge-base --all <original-branch> <new-branch>` returns only one commit.

But, as mentioned in the [`git merge-base` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base):

> When the history involves criss-cross merges, there can be more than one best common ancestor for two commits.
>   For example, with this topology:

```
---1---o---A
\ /
 X
/ \
---2---o---o---B
```

> both 1 and 2 are merge-bases of `A` and `B`. Neither one is better than the other (both are best merge bases).
>   When the `--all` option is not given, **it is unspecified which best one is output**.

Comment: In short, `git merge-base` may happen to be commutative, but the spec of that command offers no such guarantee.