# Git: Could there be a scenario where merging branch A into B gives conflicts, but merging B into A does not?

Tags: git, version-control

With git: Could there be a scenario where trying to merging branch A into B gives conflicts, but merging B into A does not?
And if this is possible, how would one create such a state?

Comment: Although it's not obvious (which means this duplicate should remain here as a duplicate), this actually is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12192526/1256452. (See all the answers there, as twalberg points out that the resulting graph topology swaps the parent commit hash ID ordering.)

Comment: @torek I'm not asking about the end result of a merge. I'm asking about possible conflicts that can arise when trying to merge.

But I guess, since the result of A->B is the same as B->A, they really have to give the same merge conflicts. Otherwise how could they end up being the same in the end?

Comment: Right - any conflicts will be the same, but (as noted in a non-main-answer) swapped around. (High level conflicts, such as rename/delete, are also swapped. For rename/rename conflicts this adjusts which name is kept by default.)